# How do I make the manifest of a .net assembly private?

Tags: .net, security, obfuscation

What should I do if I want to release a .net assembly but wish to keep its internals detailed in the manifest private (from a utility such as [ildasm.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler)) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're talking about is "obfuscation".
There are lots of articles about it on the net:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation

The "standard" tool for obfuscation on .NET is by Preemptive Solutions:

http://www.preemptive.com/obfuscator.html

They have a community edition that ships with Visual Studio which you can use.

You mentioned ILDasm, have you looked at the .NET Reflector?

http://aisto.com/roeder/dotnet/

It gives you an even better idea as to what people can see if you release a manifest!

Answer (score 1):

The CLR cannot directly load modules that contain no manifest. So you can't make an assembly completely private unless you also want to make it unloadable ;)

You can however, as Mark noted above, use obfuscation tools to hide the parts you would like to keep truly internal.

It's too bad the ***internal*** keyword doesn't exclude that metadata

EDIT: it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637/remove-meta-data-from-net-applications) is highly related